Unable to execute exetuable jar files
I am working with executable jar files
I have a folder E:\a which has Test.java and its .class files,
in E:\b. I have two classes Employee.java and student.java and there  .class files are E:\C which contains folder structure as com\emp, com\std
I have created a txt file in E:\a Main.txt which has Main-class: Test for manifest files
Now when i run jar -cvfm app.jar Main.txt e:\c to contains files at e:\c location in jar file, inside my jar files folder structure is created like inside jar C\com\emp C\com\std so when I try to run this jar file using java -jar app.jar  it is unable to find .class files of employee and student
It should execute jar file app.jar

why do you try to use an external file as manifest file?

"created like C\com\emp" -- is C part of the package, that is, is the package C.com.emp? If not, you probably want to also use the -C dir option of jar -- sorry, but the question is hard to understand :-/

You need to post a recursive listing of the directories in question. Don't mix class and source files or it will make things difficult to package

If you didn’t specify E:\a or E:\b in your jar command, it makes sense that none of those files were added to your jar.  Perhaps you wanted jar -cvfm app.jar Main.txt -C E:\a . -C E:\b . -C E:\c .?
